# Postgres | Get all ids after a promo code is used

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to get all order ids that used a specific promo code (ABC123). However, I want to see all subsequent orders, rather than just all the ids. For example, if we have the following table:

| Account_id | order_id | promo_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | NULL (no promo code used) |
| 2 | 124 | ABC123 |
| 3 | 125 | HelloWorld! |
| 2 | 125 | NULL |
| 1 | 126 | ABC123 |
| 2 | 127 | HelloWorld! |
| 3 | 128 | ABC123 |

Ideally, what I want to get is this (ordered by account_id):

| Account_id | order_id | promo_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 126 | ABC123 |
| 2 | 124 | ABC123 |
| 2 | 125 | NULL |
| 2 | 127 | HelloWorld! |
| 3 | 128 | ABC123 |

As you can see promo_code = ABC123 is like a placeholder in which all once that ID is found, I want all preceding order_ids.

So far to filer all the account_ids that used this promo_code is:

```
SELECT account_ids, order_id, promo_code
FROM orders
WHERE account_id IN (SELECT account_id FROM order WHERE promo_code = 'ABC123');
```

This allows me to get the account_ids that have an order where the desired promo_code was used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two different products

Comment: Well, Redshift runs on Postgres so I figured to tag Postgres too even though the query will run in Redshift and wanted to pass in the version of Postgres with the tag. Either way, I could reformat to fit the version.

Comment: It does not "run on Postgres". It is a complete rewrite that pretends to be Postgres. They are substantially different.

Comment: Yes, you are correct; Redshift technically is based on Postgres called (Amazon Redshift SQL) and has some subtle differences; but for this question I knew that this would not have been a big issue. If so I guess I stand corrected. Either way ,the answer below works perfect (even though DISTINCT ON () is not supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract all `account_id`-s that used 'ABC123' and the smallest corresponding `order_number`-s (the `t` CTE) then join these with the table and filter/order the result set.

```sql
with t as 
(
  select distinct on (account_id) account_id, order_id 
    from the_table where promo_code = 'ABC123' 
   order by account_id, order_id
) 
select the_table.* 
  from the_table 
 inner join t on the_table.account_id = t.account_id
 where the_table.order_id >= t.order_id -- the subsequent orders 
 order by the_table.account_id, the_table.order_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/26bab2/10)